# Flutter with fixed bottom custom navigation

Tags: flutter, appbar

What is the best way to achive custom fixed bottom navigation in flutter? At the moment I have:

```
return Scaffold(
 body: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
   Positioned(
     // Custom AppBar
   ),
   Positioned(
     // Content
   ),
   Positioned(
    // My custom fixed bottom navigation
   )
```

Then I user MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and deduct height of custom AppBar and Custom bottom navigation to get Content height. It works, but there are many problems with that approach. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use other Scaffold fields?

Comment: You mean I can build custom navigation inside scaffold bottomNavigationBar?

Comment: Yeah and your appbar within "appbar"

Comment: Ohh my god. Thank you.

Comment: I get error in appBar: The argument type 'MyAppBar' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget'. For bottomNavigationBar it works.

Comment: Wrap it into [PreferredSize](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) widget or create a widget that implements PreferredSizeWidget